# Find the end of a line in Crayon Editor by JS

Tags: javascript, php, string, wordpress

I'm using JavaScript to copy code (HTML&CSS OR PHP) from Crayon Editor plugin(for WordPress) in a blog to my compiler, then compile it.

The problem is that the code is copied as one line without formatting, and I can't determine the end of the line in Crayon by javaScript to copy every line of the code alone .

```
                $(this).prev("table").find(".crayon-line").each(function( index, element ) {
                    $(element).children('span').each(function (i,ele) {

                      if(ss==0){
                        first_element = $(ele).text();
                        ss=1;
                      }
                        // "this" is the current element in the loop
                        var ell = $(ele).text();
                        code_string=code_string+' '+ell.toString().replace("<", "&lt;");
                    })

                });
                var code_st = code_string.toString().replace(/"/g, "'");
                var code_st = code_string.toString().replace('&lt;/script>', "script>");

                var code_type="";
               //alert(code_st);
                first_element = first_element.toString().replace("<", "&lt;");

                }
```